# Querying dynamoDB with a list of elements

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I need to design a script that queries dynamoDB with a list of elements.

I've already tried looping over every element of the list, and querying that element and appending the result, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of performing that operation.

```
KeyConditionExpression=Key('id').eq('occupation') & Key('sort').begins_with(locations + '#' + occup + '#' + contract)
```

The code I've shown above performs a query for a single location, but instead of just one I wonder if I use the list and sort of lower the number of queries.

E.G.

```
locations = ['Glasgow','London']
```

and the result of this to be elements with both locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `batch_get_item` method, check [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076424/how-to-batch-get-item-many-items-at-once-given-a-list-of-primary-partition-key-v) for an example and the boto3 documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.batch_get_item).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!